# Fedora 22 loop on boot

Tags: fedora, boot, systemd

After using Fedora 22 for some time (3-4 months) I encountered a problem.

### THE PROBLEM

After choosing Fedora in grub there appears to be a loop (I do not know in what- systemd? gdm?):

```
[  OK  ] Created slice user-1000.slice.
         Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
[  OK  ] Started USer Manager for UID 1000.
         Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
[  OK  ] Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
[  OK  ] Created slice user-1000.slice.
[  OK  ] Created slice user-1000.slice.
```

### ENVIRONMENT

one system: F22 recently updated, Lenovo Think Pad L430 (intel i5, Nvidia with Optimus)
I had installed bumblebee with its latest version of NVidia drivers.

### WHAT I'VE TRIED

---

**booting another kernel verison** did not worked ( I had 2 previous kernels )

---

**booting in rescue mode and searching for clues** (logs) but I don't know what to search for and where. Can you help? From what I've searched there is not much clues.

---

**booting in rescue mode and trying to update** but I could not get connection. When I try to do something with NetworkManger eg. stop/ start I get:

```
 Error getting authority: Error initializing autority: Could not connect: No such file or directory (g-io-error-quark, 1)
```

I've tried also to rollback via `dnf history rollback` but since I do not have a network connection, the package manager could not download uninstalled packages (I had turned off cache/backup packages by default)

### SIMILAR PROBLEMS

[ref 1](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/77841/fedora-22-boot-loop-after-updating-to-kernel-425/)

### QUESTION

Can someone tell me how to fix this issue? Or to get connection so as I can try to rollback or something, please! Ask for logs and I'll post what is needed.

Comment: I'm not _quite_ clear on the problem. Do you mean that the system boot stops at the above? Does the final line repeat more than twice?

Comment: And, did this start right after installing the Nvidia drivers?

Comment: yes, it's a loop (look up screen in "ref 1" in SIMILAR PROBLEMS section. The drivers was not touched, they were working just fine for some time. I do not know what caused this issue.

Comment: I have clicked to update drivers (in NVidia's GUI), but it said that drivers are up to date and there is nothing to download (or sth like that). I dont remember if it was just before the last restart or earlier.

Comment: I've tried to chroot and update also, reinstall systemd, uninstall bumblebee etc. Nothing worked. Ended up installing fresh F23  :( I feel defeated...

Comment: oh, I found out that I had /etc/log mounted on tmpfs (for ssd optimization)- that's why I had no logs :( I won't do this again for sure!

Comment: Hmmmmmmm. It sounds like there's a number of odd things you may be doing. It seems likely that you broke something in doing one of them.

Comment: number of odd things? Maybe the "logs int tempfs" was not the smartest idea (not mine) but where are the other "odd" things?

Comment: I don't know! What else did you do?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptom, after moving a F23 installation (ssd) to a different motherboard+chipset. The solution was to change the Secure Boot settings in BIOS. It was set to "Windows 7," and I set it to "Other OS." I guess the first motherboard had this setting by default.

I became aware that this may be the issue when I tried to reinstall the Nvidia driver (since I was able to get to terminal 2) and it asked me about kernel module signing, since it detected that Secure Boot was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same in Fedora 24 boot (start - stop - remove user 1000 loop after boot)

My simple solution (worked on both my machines):

-Alt-F[3-6] to prompt at console.

-Just wait a minute or so to let the screen calm down

-login as root

-go to init 3 (non graphical login boot mode) with command 'telinit 3'

-in init 3 mode, give command 'reboot'

-reboot flawlessly comes up in init 5 at GDM login screen

I still don't know why this works - but it does ;)